# Why must an inertial navigation system take the Coriolis effect into account?

Tags: classical-mechanics

I read somewhere that an inertial navigation system, in order to be accurate, must take the Coriolis effect into account. Why is this so? If I go a 500 mph velocity in a given direction, I'm going 500 mph, so in 1 hour, I should be 500 miles from the airport whether I'm traveling N, E, or W.

Comment: Inertial sensors sense motion in an inertial frame. While accelerometers and gyros will sense motion in the local frame, they also sense earth motion. Coriolis force is a cross product of the two, sensed by the sensors.

Comment: @docscience You say accelerometers and gyros sense earth motion. Will you please explain this a little more or link to another site? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To a stationary observer on Earth watching you travel in the same direction in which the Earth rotates, you might be going 500 mph. Galilean relativity says that you are moving 500 mph relative to Earth, and the Earth is moving 500 mph relative to you.However, since the Earth is rotating, that stationary observer is also rotating. So if you're travelling in a different direction, what would otherwise be 500 mph is now 500 + how quickly the Earth is rotating.